# Expression trees resolving differently in 4.5 than in 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, delegates, lambda

I have recently upgraded a .NET 3.5 web app to .NET 4.5.  In part of the app we build a predicate to query data in the cache and add the filters(appending to a predicate).  Sometimes I might add the same WHERE multiple times with different data (itemCode = 123 AND itemCode = 456).  In 3.5 this works and in 4.5 it doesn't (it actually seems like it shouldn't work in either, I am just wondering what changed).  When I inspect the predicate (the code to build it didn't change in the conversion to 4.5), here is the difference I see:

```
{f => ((((True && Invoke(e => ((Convert(e.IsItem) != null) && (e.IsItem = value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass26).nei)),f)) && Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) && (e.VendorNumber = value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)),f)) && Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) && (e.VendorNumber = value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)),f)) && Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) && (e.VendorNumber = value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)),f))}


{f => ((((True AndAlso Invoke(e => ((Convert(e.IsItem) != null) AndAlso (e.IsItem == value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass24).nei)), f)) AndAlso Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) AndAlso (e.VendorNumber == value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)), f)) AndAlso Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) AndAlso (e.VendorNumber == value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)), f)) AndAlso Invoke(e => ((e.VendorNumber != null) AndAlso (e.VendorNumber == value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)), f))}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?  Does AndAlso work differently than &&?

Comment: That's not compilable code.  Can you provide an example of *compilable* code that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: That looks like it's just a difference in string representation.

Comment: I am with @JonSkeet here.

Comment: @leppie Well all with JonSkeet here :)

Comment: I agree.  But the first one returns values when only one of the expressions (e.VendorNumber = value(AvailableItems+<>c__DisplayClass0).filter.ColumnValue)),f)) is true